# Capacity of Z Channel

Tags: information-theory

Calculating the capacity of the Z channel (binary asymmetric channel) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-channel_(information_theory)), the entropy $ H(Y)$ isn't supposed to be $ H(Y)=H(a+(1-a)p,(1-a)(1-p))$ ? What's the reason for having $H(Y)=H((1-a)(1-p))$ ?

Comment: You write $H(Y)=H( \cdot,\cdot)$ (two arguments?) What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: This notation is used in the classic textbook for Information Theory by Cover and Thomas to express the different probabilities of a RV when plugging them in the entropy sum expression.

Comment: "This notation is used" ... I don't think so. Check it.

Comment: I think that example 2.2.1 in page 18 uses this notation.

Comment: Of course, H(X,Y) makes sense for _two random variables_.  That's not your case.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of Example 2.2.1 where that notation is used in Cover and Thomas: https://imgur.com/a/iKpRPgK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a common abuse of notation here: $H(\cdot)$ can mean two very different things.

$H(X)$ (the argument is a random variable) means the entropy of a random variable $X$ (with some given density).

$H(a)$, when the argument is a scalar (more specifically, a real number in $[0,1]$), means the "binary entropy", that is, the entropy of a Bernoulli variable with paramenter $a$ ($P[X=1]=a)$. Hence  $H(a) = -a \log(a) -(1-a) \log(1-a)$

In the deduction , $Y$ is a Bernoulli variable, hence $H(Y)=H(p)$ where the two sides of the equation use (perhaps confusingly) the two different notations, the right side is the binary entropy, and $p=P(Y=1)$

Update: Using (for avoiding confusion) the notation $H(X)$ for the entropy of a random variable and $h_b( p)$ the binary entropy function. In the Z channel case we have a random variable $Y$ (output) which is a Bernoulli variable . Hence $H(Y) = h_b(t)$ where $t=P(Y=1)$ (I use the variable name $t$ to avoid -another- confusion with $p=$  probability of channel crossover).

Now, $$t=P(Y=1)= P(X=1 \cap {\rm no crossover})=(1-\alpha)(1-p)$$

Hence $$H(Y)= h_b(t)=h_b((1-\alpha)(1-p))$$

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Though I'm kinda confused:Shouldn't the Η(Υ) take into account both the probabilities that Y=1 and Y=0?  It seems like H(Y)=H(Y=1)=H((1-a)(1-p)).. Why is H(Y)=H(Y=1)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I never wrote $H(Y)=H(Y=1)$, please reread.

Comment: If your are still confused, you should change the notation to help you distinguish those two very different things.. For example, use $H(X)$ for the entropy of a random variable, and use $h_b(p)$ for the binary entropy function. Then $H(X)=h_b(p)$ where $p=P(Y=1)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand the separation you are pointing out :) The confusing point I'm trying to make out is according to the wiki article $H(Y)=H((1-a)(1-p))$ , while you concluded that $H(Y)=H(p)$, which seems reasonable ;)

Comment: It seems you are falling into another notation confusion ($p$ as argument of the binary entropy function, and the $p$ of the channel). See my update.

Comment: Many thanks! :)